# Validation through getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm been trying to validate my fields by using 'getElementById()' with '.value'. However, it seems like either getElementById.value is not working or some codes has overlap the function.

Updated Javascript function:

```
function validate() {
    var Name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    var Tel = document.getElementById('Tel').value;
    var FaxNo = document.getElementById('FaxNo').value;
    if (Name != "") //wanted to check for alphabets only.
    {
         alert("Correct");
         return true; //doesnt go to next.php
    }
    else 
    {
          alert("Don leave blank!")
          return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(Tel)) //check only numbers. Same code for FaxNo.
    {
        alert("Correct");
        return true; //doesnt go to next.php
    }
    else 
    {
      alert("invalid");
      return false
    }

  return true; //doesn't go to next.php
}
```

My Form:

```
<Form action ="next.php" method="post">
<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" value=""/>
<input name="Tel" type="text" id="Tel" value=""/>
<input name="FaxNo" type="text" id="FaxNo" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate();"/>
</Form>
```

I have already defined my onclick function to my Javascript and tried to add return false too. But the alert still cant appear. Kindly advise.

Comment: Works for me in chrome...http://jsfiddle.net/dr7qu/

Comment: @jeschafe no it doesn't, the form submits regardless of invalid input. He must use `onsubmit` and `return false` or prevent default.

Comment: @jeschafe, it will submit still. But if i put return false behind. It wont call my next.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your markup is invalid:

```
<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" " value=""/>
                                         ^-----------should be removed
```

so correction would be removing all extra `"` characters:

```
<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" value=""/>
<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" value=""/>
<input name="Tel" type="text" id="Tel" value=""/>
<input name="FaxNo" type="text" id="FaxNo" value=""/>
```

For preventing submition,when input is invalid, you can try something like a:

```
function validate() {
    var Name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    var Tel = document.getElementById('Tel').value;
    var FaxNo = document.getElementById('FaxNo').value;

    if (Name != "") //wanted to check for alphabets only.
        alert("Correct")
    else {
        alert("Don leave blank!")
        return false;
    }

    if (isNumeric(Tel)) //check only numbers. Same code for FaxNo.
        alert("Correct")
    else {
        alert("invalid");
        return false;
    }
}
//Borrowed from jQuery lib
function isNumeric( obj ){
    return !isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite( obj )
}

<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate()"/>
```

Comment: that's my typo mistake during posting. the getelementbyid is not recognised. Unable to get thevalue

Comment: @JLearner Your script [works fine](http://jsbin.com/esihoc/edit#preview), only the markup was invalid.

Comment: @Engineer  no it doesn't, the form submits regardless of invalid input. He must use onsubmit and return false or prevent default.

Comment: @Esailija The goal of the OP is to show the alert-> `"But the alert still cant appear"`

Comment: @Engineer but his ultimate goal would be not submitting the form if it was invalid? Otherwise the code is useless

Comment: @Esailija Yes, the ultimate goal could be that, but showing the alert was the main problem.Other problems(preventing the sumbit when values are invalid) can be resolved by the OP.

Comment: good answer. only suggestion would be binding the event handler in javascript instead of markup.

Comment: Hi, please see my updated code on top. When i return true; it doesnt go to the next.php

Comment: @jbabey You are right, but I have tried to change the OP's code as less as possible.

Comment: @JLearner It should go, just fill `Name` field by some text.

Comment: @Engineer thanks it works. But do u have any idea why 'isNaN' doesn't work on checking numbers?

Comment: @JLearner What do you want to validate?  Is `Tel` number or not?

Comment: yup, to validate if it is number.

Comment: @JLearner Check my answer, that is the only correct way for validating whether the `obj` is Number.

Comment: great thanks. It won't be possible to have a preg_match function isnt it ? like php ? What if validate with a space like alphabets with space

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14013/discussion-between-engineer-and-jlearner)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function validate() {
    var Name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    var Tel = document.getElementById('Tel').value;
    var FaxNo = document.getElementById('FaxNo').value;
    if (Name != "") {}
    else {alert("Don leave blank!"); return false;}
    if (isNaN(Tel)){ alert("invalid"); return false;}
    else { }
return true;
}
```

Your HTML submit button code should be

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate()"/>
```

Use return false to prevent submitting form in case of any validation errors.

Comment: in this case, when i return validate(). it wont execute my next.php isn't it? Even i place my return true in Name!""

Comment: It will not allow form submission if validation is not satisfied otherwise it will.

Comment: by the way what you mean by " Even i place my return true in Name!"? sorry I don't understand :D

Comment: please see my updated javascript code. at my comment for return truel

Comment: ya it works. May i know if the function isNaN for validating numbers wont work ?

Comment: isNaN means is not a number. You can use it for validation. It will return true if the passed value is not a number, false otherwise. In your case if you want to only allow numbers in fax and tel textboxes you should change if condition as in the above answer.